# Jquery autocomplete loops HTTP requests

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a problem with the JQuery autocomplete plugin.

It's hard for me to explain but whenever I try to press a key it keeps looping with requests to the server.

See:

[image: loop]
http://members.lycos.nl/saccon/loop.jpg

It should only request once!
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What plugin do you use and how do you use it?

Comment: as Gumbo said, you should provide us with some code for us to be able to help you.

Comment: a yeah sorry bout that..

JS code I Use:
<pre>
AutoCompleteStations = function()
{
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
     $("#stations").autocomplete('http://' + server + '/Ajax/ajaxstations', 
  {
   minChars: 2,
      lineSeparator: '\n',
      cellSeparator: '|',
      extraParams: {'countryId': function() { return $("#countries option:selected").val();}},
     formatItem: 
       function(row) 
       { 
     return row['value'] 
    },
  });
 }); 
}
</pre>

Comment: html code:
<input type="text" name="stations" id="stations" value="" onkeyup="AutoCompleteStations()" autocomplete="off" />

Comment: with this plugin:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/source/browse/jquery.autocomplete.js

Answer (score 0):

You have created a loop by wrapping the `$(document).ready` call in another function `AutoCompleteStations` the code should appear as below.

Also you don't need to call a function from the input directly, so you can remove the onkeyup event from the input tag.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#stations").autocomplete('http://' + server + '/Ajax/ajaxstations', { 
        minChars: 2, lineSeparator: '\n', cellSeparator: '|', extraParams: {
            'countryId': function() { 
                return $("#countries option:selected").val();
            }
        },
        formatItem: function(row) { 
            return row['value']; 
        }
     });
});
```